# Find differences betwen 2 dataframes with different lengths

Tags: r

I have two dataframes with each two columns `c("price", "size")` with different lengths.

Each price must be linked to its size. It's two lists of trade orders. I have to discover the differences between the two dataframes knowing that the two databases can have orders that the other doesn't have and vice versa. I would like an output with the differences or two outputs, it doesn't matter.  But I need the row number in the output to find where are the differences in the series.

Here is sample data :

```
> out
           price       size
     1: 36024.86 0.01431022
     2: 36272.00 0.00138692
     3: 36272.00 0.00277305
     4: 36292.57 0.05420000
     5: 36292.07 0.00403948
    ---                    
923598: 35053.89 0.30904890
923599: 35072.76 0.00232000
923600: 35065.60 0.00273000
923601: 35049.36 0.01760000
923602: 35037.23 0.00100000

>bit 
      price       size
     1: 37279.89 0.01340020
     2: 37250.84 0.00930000
     3: 37250.32 0.44284049
     4: 37240.00 0.00056491
     5: 37215.03 0.99891906
    ---                    
923806: 35053.89 0.30904890
923807: 35072.76 0.00232000
923808: 35065.60 0.00273000
923809: 35049.36 0.01760000
923810: 35037.23 0.00100000
```

For example, I need to know if the first row of the database `out` is in the database `bit`.
I've tried many functions : `comparedf()`

```
summary(comparedf(bit, out, by = c("price","size"))
```

but I've got error:

> Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin ||
> !anyDuplicated(f__, :

I've tried `compare_df()` :

```
compareout=compare_df(out,bit,c("price","size"))
```

But I know the results are wrong, I've only 23 results and I know that there are more than 200 differences minimum.

I've tried `match()`, `which()` functions but it doesn't get the results I search.

If you have any other methods, I will take them.

Comment: You might want to supply a small example dataset to showcase your problem. It's almost impossible to help you without any concrete example.

Comment: hard to answer without sample data

Comment: sorry guys, it's updated

Comment: So the row number is your only ID? And you want to compare price and size? Or is every price or size unique in your table?

Comment: Yes the row number is my unique ID and I want to compare price and size. When I use setdiff(bit, out), I have 19 outputs and setdiff(out, bit), I have 4 outputs, so here is the difficulty. I know there are 208 more rows in "bit", so there are surely duplicates...

Comment: The extra rows make it tricky. If you think the tables will be the same size after removing duplicates I can work something out but as you can see using row numbers as unique IDs can be a slippery slope

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could just do `inner_join` on `out` and `bit` by `price` and `size`? But first make id variable for both data.frame's

```
library(dplyr)

out$id <- 1:nrow(out)
bit$id <- 1:nrow(bit)

joined <- inner_join(bit, out, by = c("price", "size"))
```

Now we can check which id from out and bit are not present in `joined` table:

```
id_from_bit_not_included_in_out <- bit$id[!bit$id %in% joined$id.x]
id_from_out_not_included_in_bit <- out$id[!out$id %in% joined$id.y]
```

And these ids are the rows not included in `out` or `bit`, i.e. variable `id_from_bit_not_included_in_out` contains rows present in bit, but not in out and variable `id_from_out_not_included_in_bit` contains rows present in `out`, but not in `bit`

Comment: Maybe I have made wrong assumption - I understand that you want to know if e.g. row 1 from "bit" is present in "out", not if row 1 from "bit" is present in row 1 in "out"

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! 
The identification variable is a very good idea. However, the outputs are always 19 differences and 4 differences because the ID is not unique in the `inner join`. A "bit" ID can be attribute multiple times to many "out" rows. It's difficult to be clear, tell me if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

First attempt here. It will be difficult to do a very clean job with this data tho.

The data I used:

```
out <- read.table(text = "price       size
                  36024.86 0.01431022
                  36272.00 0.00138692
                  36272.00 0.00277305
                  36292.57 0.05420000
                  36292.07 0.00403948
                                      
                  35053.89 0.30904890
                  35072.76 0.00232000
                  35065.60 0.00273000
                  35049.36 0.01760000
                  35037.23 0.00100000", header = T)
 
bit <- read.table(text = "price       size
                  37279.89 0.01340020
                  37250.84 0.00930000
                  37250.32 0.44284049
                  37240.00 0.00056491
                  37215.03 0.99891906
                  37240.00 0.00056491
                  37215.03 0.99891906               
                  35053.89 0.30904890
                  35072.76 0.00232000
                  35065.60 0.00273000
                  35049.36 0.01760000
                  35037.23 0.00100000", header = T)
```

Assuming purely that row 1 of out should match with row 1 of bit a simple solution could be:

```
df <- cbind(distinct(out), distinct(bit))
names(df) <- make.unique(names(df))
```

However judging from the data you have provided I am not sure if this is the way to go (big differences in the first few rows) so maybe try sorting the data first?:

```
df <- cbind(distinct(out[order(out$price, out$size),]), distinct(bit[order(bit$price, bit$size),]))
names(df) <- make.unique(names(df))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
But the `distinct` doesn't work because the length of the dataframes are not the same...